# Unit testing mongo map reduce functions with both local scope and object scope variables

Tags: javascript, mongodb, unit-testing

I would like to unit test JavaScript functions used for querying MongoDB with map reduce algorithm.

#### Simple map function

```
function mapFunction() {
   if(key !== this.key) {
      return;
   }
   // do reduce logic
}
```

- `this.key` variable is MongoDB's object property (`this` provides access to all properties of such object).
- `key` is a scope variable (scope object is provided to the map reduce query separately).

The purpose of `mapFunction`'s `if` statement is, simply, to ignore MongoDB objects when their key does not match one provided in the scope.

#### Unit testing map function

To simulate MongoDB context, both `key` and `this.key` variables need to be set by the test framework.

Mocking `this.key` can be easily done by using `Function.prototype.apply` function:

```
var mongoContext = {
   key: "sampleKey"
};
mapFunction.apply(mongoContext);
```

#### Question

I would like to know how to mock `key` value in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `mapFunction` in a calling function and set the scope there as needed.

The `key` variable will fall back to `window` unless it is shadowed further down the chain. Should be appropriate for your problem.

See http://jsbin.com/sipili/1/edit?js,output for example.